# Mean and variance calculation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

An unfair coin has probability $p$ of heads. I ﬂip it until I get heads, then
I ﬂip it some more until I get tails. Let $X$ be the total number of ﬂips. So
here are some possible outcomes:

HT : $X = 2$

THT : $X = 3$

HHHHT : $X = 5$

TTHHHHT : $X = 7$

1. Find the mean and variance of $X$. Hint: write $X$ as the sum of
   two random variables.
2. Now let $Y$ be the number of heads minus the number of tails. Find the
   mean and variance of $Y$ .

**Ans:**

What i tried here is , let $X$ be the prob of head and $1-X$ is the prob of tail.
By definition
$H(x)=−\sum_nP(X)\log_2P(X)$.
Probability that number of flips is $X$ is probability that $X-1$ times tail is shown and on $X$−th time is head.

But since this is a unfair coin , i am confused as to how to proceed.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The entropy H has nothing to do here. Why do you invoke it?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

Following the hint you can split $X$ in to two independent r.v's $X_1$ and $X_2$, where $X_1$ is the number of flips you'll have to perform to get heads (with probability $p$ in each trial) for the first time and $X_2$ the number of flips you'll have to perform to get tails (with probability $1-p$ in each trial) after that. 

 So you can see that each of them obey [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). Can you follow?

**UPD**

By the definition:

"The geometric distribution is the probability that the first occurrence of success require $k$ number of independent trials, each with success probability $p$"

So for $X_1$ is the number of flips you'll have to make to get first heads (with the probability of getting heads in each flip equal to $p$).

Comment: But what about the number of trials, how that can come into account?

Comment: @manayay is it more clear now?

Answer (score -3):

Following the hint we can split X in to two independent r.v's Xnd Y, where
Xis the number of flips you'll have to perform to get heads (with probability p in each trial) for the first time

and Y the number of flips you'll have to perform to get tails (with probability 1−p in each trial) after that.
So you can see that each of them obey geometric distribution.

The probability distribution of the number X of bernoulli trial needed to get one success, supported on the set {1,2,3,...}
The probability distribution of the number Y =X−1 of failures before the first success, supported on the set {0,1,2,3,...}

It’s the probability that the first occurrence of success require k number of independent trials, each with success probability p.If the probability of success on each trial is p, then the probability that the kth trial (out of k trials) is the first success is

The above form of geometric distribution is used for modeling the number of trials until the first success. By contrast, the following form of geometric distribution is used for modeling number of failures until the first success:

In either case, the sequence of probabilities is a geometric seq.

The expected value of a geometrically distributed random variable X is 1/p and the variance is (1 − p)/p2:

Similarly, the expected value of the geometrically distributed random variable Y  is (1−p)/p, and its variance is (1−p)/p2 .

Comment: shouldn't it be placed inside the quotation marks since it is completely taken from Wikipedia?

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache Did not get you, yes its from wiki

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache What is the value of X, Y and p here? What values are to be put in the equation wiki provides, that is the question.

Comment: taking something from somewhere without **any** reference is at least _not nice_ (let's call it like that).